# What is making the glow from this image of STS-135 going home, de-orbit burn or re-entry?

Tags: reentry, space-shuttle, photography

I found the image below in a [NASA image gallery for 2014](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOIOE.jpg). There, the text only says:

> This unprecedented view of the space shuttle Atlantis, appearing like a bean sprout against clouds and city lights, on its way home, was photographed by the Expedition 28 crew of the International Space Station. Airglow over Earth can be seen in the background.
>
> Image Credit: NASA, Last Updated: July 31, 2015, Editor: NASA Administrator
>
> Tags:  Expedition 28, Landings, Shuttle Atlantis, Space Shuttle, STS-135

Is the visible glow from a de-orbit burn, or heat from re-entry, or something else? Since it's moving away from the camera, why would the light be visible in either case? There's a bump or knee in the trail, highlighted in the second, annotated/cropped image. What probably caused it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is the reentry.

Comment: A de-orbit burn wouldn't be nearly that noticeable; hypergolics burn fairly faintly even in-atmosphere, and in vacuum the plume would diffuse very rapidly. The Proton first stage is about 200 times as powerful as OMS and looks like this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMwDASkWPJU

Comment: Also the deorbit burn only lasted a few minutes - on STS-120, for example, it was 198 seconds.

Comment: The term "*airglow*" hints on atmospheric effects which would not be present during deorbit burn.

Comment: @jkavalik that's interesting, why not? Is that more because the re-entry is highter temperature, or more because the total amount of energy involved is higher, or because the altitude would be lower and the density higher and therefore the number of molecules that can glow is greater?

Comment: @uhoh at 300-400km (at or a bit below ISS orbit which I believe should be where the deorbit burn usually happened) there is really no air. Sure it is far from perfect vacuum but not enough to create any significant pressure or cascading effects - my idea is that when you bump a molecule it goes long way before interacting with anything else whereas generating a glow requires each misplaced molecule to bump other quickly enough and in such numbers it sustains some kind of reaction (but I maybe wrong, intuition does not work well at those levels and I did not study anything closely related)

Comment: @jkavalik that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your picture shows the plasma trail behind STS-135, the last space shuttle entry in history.

> The trail you’re seeing is therefore not actually the Orbiter
>   streaking across the Earth! The plasma trail behind it fades with
>   time, so the trail is brightest near the Orbiter’s position and
>   fainter as you backtrack along its path. Think of it as an afterglow
>   of the passing of Atlantis.
>
> Why does this happen? The air gets heated by the Orbiter’s ramming the
>   atmosphere at 20+ times the speed of sound. And contrary to popular
>   belief, it’s not friction that heats the air, but compression. When
>   you compress a gas it heats up (like when a bicycle pump gets hot when
>   you use it a lot), and the Orbiter is screaming through the atmosphere
>   at hypersonic speeds. That compresses the air a lot. A shock wave
>   forms in front of the Orbiter, and the air begins to glow as it gets
>   heated up to temperatures as high as 1260° C (2300° F).
>
> That’s what you’re seeing above: the shocked, rammed, and glowing air
>   as Atlantis pounded through it at several kilometers per second. And
>   it did this many, many times over its life… until this one final time,
>   caught on camera by astronauts high above the Earth.

[source](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2011/07/22/the-fiery-descent-of-atlantis-seen-from-space/)

Plasma trails were also visible from the ground if one was in the right place at the right time, as in this incredible picture of the STS-93 entry over Johnson Space Center.  I was standing outside watching this in person, but I did not take this picture, sadly.

[image]

Here is a picture of the STS-107 plasma trail over California, before things went visibly wrong.

[image]

I do not know what caused the bump in the trail, but possible causes are:

- a maneuver by the shuttle (roll reversal)
- high altitude winds or other meteorology

Comment: The bump looks like the roll reversal to me, as the trail curves noticeably afterward.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  Wind would be pretty diffuse up there.

Comment: I guess it had to be a plasma trail. The exposure is fairly short (maybe a few seconds or so?) but the trail is fairly long, so it must be just sitting there glowing. That would explain the steady increase in brightness getting closer to the location of the shuttle itself. OK this makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: To the (my) human eye, the STS-93 plasma trail looked just like the picture, a long meteor-like trail that slowly faded away at the end.

Comment: What's the place with all the radio dishes in the foreground of the STS-107 photo?

Comment: That is the Owens Valley Radio Observatory north of Bishop, California.  https://www.ovro.caltech.edu/